# NASM x86_64 printf float printing

Tags: c, macos, printf, nasm, x86-64

I tried to use `printf` within assembly code to print some floats (doubles to be precise), but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Code (Intel syntax)

```
global start
extern exit
extern printf

section .data

x dq 3.14
format db '%f',0

section .text

start:
    default rel ;64-bit uses realtive addressing
    
    mov rbp, rsp
    and rsp, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0 ;stack alignment
    
    movsd xmm0, [x]
    lea rdi, [format]
    mov rax, 1
    call printf
        
    mov qword[rsp], 0
    call exit
```

To build I use

```
nasm seven.asm -fmacho64 --prefix _
ld seven.o -o seven -arch x86_64 -lc -e _start -macosx_version_min 10.6
```

And the output is simply `0.000000`

I have **Macbook Pro 2013** with **Intel Core i5** processor, **OS X El Capitan**

## EDIT

Thanks to you guys, the answer is `nasm` bug, which appears somewhere in 2.11.06-2.11.08 version, causing everrything in data section to be overwritten except last instruction. And the soulution was to revert to 2.11.05.

Comment: How do you know the number to be printed is passed in `xmm0`? Maybe compile a simple C application that does just that, disassemble it and take a look to get to know the ABI.

Comment: Works on my machine.

Comment: @szczurcio I consulted [AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), and every guide out there insist on this ABI, so I'm pretty sure it is right to pass doubles in `xmm0`. By the way, Disassembling leads to (almost) same code.

Comment: @FUZxxl Could you please share your nasm version (`nasm -v`) and ld version (`ld -v`)?

Comment: nasm 2.11.05 and GNU ld 2.25. I tested this on Linux, so the result might be different.

Comment: Any chance you are encountering this bug? (What version of NASM are you using) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385380/awkward-data-section-behavior-with-nasm

Comment: If you're using nasm 2.11.08, this might be the [known bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31736983/224132) with data-section labels.  Since FUZxxl reports that it works on Linux, this seems likely.  I think the OS X function-call ABI is *exactly* the same as the Linux 64bit ABI, including passing the first 8 float/double args in xmm registers.  And passing the number of vector regs used as arguments to a varargs function in `al`